# Working with SVG on Android

Tags: android, svg

I need to develop a small game that should use SVG elements.
I know I can use the android svg library.
My question is what performance should I expect from this library - is it good enough?
Are there any other good libraries I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good enough for what? You need to be more specific. The Android graphics package has native implementation for most (all?) of the SVG primitives, so the only overhead of the library should come from parsing the XML. Drawing/refresh speed will mostly depend on the actual device hardware, so you'll need to benchmark with a specific device in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/ it was used by google in Androidify and from my experience it is the best solution out there  (although it doesn't support the full SVG spec).

Answer (score 0):

There is also AndroidSVG (http://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/) which implements more of the spec than svg-android.